# No degrees of freedom in LR rest of multinomial logistic regression

Tags: chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution, degrees-of-freedom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Likelihood Ratio Testing in Multinomial logistic regression using SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28656/likelihood-ratio-testing-in-multinomial-logistic-regression-using-spss)

I am doing multinomial logistic regression.

Dependent variable is categorical with 6 categories.
15 Independent variables are measured on an interval scale (included as covariates in SPSS)

Now I am watching the LR test. None of the independent variables have a chi-square value and no degrees of freedom are shown, so significance is not specified. (except for the constant, which is significant and has 5 df's).

When I omit one IV in the model, there are chisquare values, df's and significance values for the independent variables. Was the first model over-parametrised or something?

what is the explanation for this situation? And is it valid to omit one independent variable in the model?

Comment: What's your sample size? Sounds like you had as many df's used as you had. If so, then the second model is also overfit.

Comment: Sample size is 500 respondents (cases) for each category. So, in total 3.000 respondents.

Comment: Does this happen when you omit _any_ predictors, or only when you omit a particular one?  Perhaps you have exact collinearity among your predictors. For example, are any of your predictors averages of any other predictors?

Comment: It happens when I omit any predictor, so I think the first model was overfitted/over-parameterised?